# Is there an standard way to get a full URL similar to the way image.src works

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a relative, absolute and full qualified URLs that I want to turn into fully qualified URLs. I can do this by abusing the img tag like this

```js
[
   "someFolder/someFile.foo",                       // relative
   "/someRootFolder/someFile.foo",                  // absolute
   "https://somedomain.com/someFolder/someFile.foo", // FQ
].forEach(path => {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = path;
  console.log(img.src);  // returns FQ for all URLs;
});
```

If you run it the result is

```
https://stacksnippets.net/someFolder/someFile.foo
https://stacksnippets.net/someRootFolder/someFile.foo
https://somedomain.com/someFolder/someFile.foo
```

It's seems wrong to abuse `Image` to do this. First it's an image tag and my URLs have nothing to do with images and second I don't want to trigger a network request.

`URL` doesn't work as it will fail on both first 2 URLs

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

I thought maybe `window.location` would have a function `getURL` or something you could pass a path to and it would require whatever it's doing for image.src but I don't see anything on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Is the another way that's just as simple (1/2 lines) but doesn't use the image tag and doesn't cause a network request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually done with an `<a>` tag.

```js
[
   "someFolder/someFile.foo",                       // relative
   "/someRootFolder/someFile.foo",                  // absolute
   "http://somedomain.com/someFolder/someFile.foo", // FQ
].forEach(path => {
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = path;
  console.log(a.href);  // returns FQ for all URLs;
});
```

Which also has other advantages over an `<img>` in that it contains some `window.location` like properties :

like `hash`, `pathname`, `path`, `origin`, and maybe others I forgot.

```js
[
   "someFolder/someFile.foo#hi",                       // relative
   "/someRootFolder/someFile.foo#hi",                  // absolute
   "http://somedomain.com/someFolder/someFile.foo#hi", // FQ
].forEach(path => {
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = path;
  console.log(a.pathname, a.origin, a.host, a.hash);  // and maybe some others
});
```

Comment: Any particular reason why `Object.assign` instead of just `a.href = `?

Comment: @gman, nope, but you started with ES6 syntax, so one-liner... But it's exactly the same as `let a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = path;` Edited.